# Improve Keras Model for text classification

Tags: python, lstm, text-classification

I am making a model for **classification of webpages titles** into one of 101 classes regarding food (most of the titles regard recipes). The medium length of my sequences is 42. I cleaned the text (bad words, changed to lowercase etc) and tokenized it using a Tokenizer. I put a **LSTM** layer in my model, and I get 83% accuracy on the test set. I'm pretty sure this can be improved making some changes to the network, do you have any suggestions? Thank you in advance! That's my model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(MAX_NB_WORDS, EMBEDDING_DIM, input_length=x_train.shape[1]))
model.add(SpatialDropout1D(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(100, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2))
model.add(Dense(101, activation='softmax'))

opt = optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, amsgrad=False)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you could try to do is to add another LSTM layer, but please pay attention to the number of units: increasing them too much can easily lead to overfitting. Otherwise, gradually reducing the learning rate when you reach a plateau could also contribute to an increase.

If you add another one, do not forget to add "`return_sequences=True`" in the first LSTM layer.

You should also have a validation set reserved for metrics (apart from the test set).

Comment: Thank you Timbus! So I add another LSTM layer decreasing the number of neurons. Should I add another SpatialDropout1D in between of the 2 LSTM?

Comment: Only after the embedding does the spatialdropout make sense. Between LSTM layes, you can use the dropout argument and recurrent_dropout argument on an LSTM layer, like you used